# cloudera trash checkpoint interval configuration

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

Cloudera allows me to configure fs.trash.interval.

But it doesn't allow me to conigure fs.trash.checkpoint.interval.

So when does hdfs creates a checkpoint ?

A similar question exists here without response:
[When does Hadoop Framework creates a checkpoint (expunge) to its "current" directory in trash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698854/when-does-hadoop-framework-creates-a-checkpoint-expunge-to-its-current-direc)

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.3/) documentation includes links in the left navigation to various *-default.xml files.  These files contain the default settings for all configuration properties.

If you click through the *-default.xml links, the website shows them in pretty-printed tables.  Here is the raw XML version from [core-site.xml](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/resources/core-default.xml#L525-L548) discussing the trash properties.

```
<property>
  <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>Number of minutes after which the checkpoint
  gets deleted.  If zero, the trash feature is disabled.
  This option may be configured both on the server and the
  client. If trash is disabled server side then the client
  side configuration is checked. If trash is enabled on the
  server side then the value configured on the server is
  used and the client configuration value is ignored.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.trash.checkpoint.interval</name>
  <value>0</value>
  <description>Number of minutes between trash checkpoints.
  Should be smaller or equal to fs.trash.interval. If zero,
  the value is set to the value of fs.trash.interval.
  Every time the checkpointer runs it creates a new checkpoint 
  out of current and removes checkpoints created more than 
  fs.trash.interval minutes ago.
  </description>
</property>
```

Based on this description, if you haven't changed `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`, then it uses the same value as `fs.trash.interval`, and that's how frequently it would create a trash checkpoint.

The `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval` configuration property was introduced in the Apache Hadoop 2.x release line.  Older releases did not support this configuration property, and you could think of the behavior as being equivalent to having `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval` equal to `fs.trash.interval`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But on the cloudera distribution there is no definition of fs.trash.checkpoint.interval. So I don't understand the way checkpoints are created ?

Comment: @mvera, is it possible that you are running an older version of CDH based on Apache Hadoop 1.x instead of 2.x?  I have added another paragraph explaining that the `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval` configuration property was introduced in Apache Hadoop 2.x and what the behavior was like in 1.x.  If you're confident that you're running a version that supports `fs.trash.checkpoint.interval`, then perhaps this is just a matter of what CDH surfaces to users through management tools like Cloudera Manager.

Comment: we use a recent cloudera 5.9 distribution.